# How do I call TCPConn.SetLinger()?

Tags: go

I'm using Go 1.2 and trying to call TCPConn.SetLinger(0) on a socket that my server is closing due to fatal errors in the input.  However, I can't figure out how I would do this.  Both net.Listener.Accept() and TCPListener.Accept() return net.Conn, not net.TCPConn.  net.Conn does not implement SetLinger.  I tried doing a type switch, but then the compiler complains of an "impossible type switch case: conn (type net.Conn) cannot have dynamic type net.TCPConn (missing Close method)".  How can net.TCPConn be missing a Close method??  I haven't checked the source, but the documentation lists a close method (and what kind of connection can you not close, anyway?).

It seems like you cannot cast net.Conn to net.TCPConn (because of no Close method), and you can't get a TCPConn on a server, because all the Accept()s return a net.Conn.  So how do I actually call SetLinger?  (Or for that matter, SetKeepAlive, SetNoDelay?)

After looking more closely, it looks like there is a net.TCPListener.AcceptTCP() which returns a TCPListener, is that really what I have to do?  Why can't I get a TCPConn from Accept()?  I started it off with net.Listen("tcp", ":4321"), so I know it has to be a TCPConn underneath...

Comment: In your type switch, are you checking for `net.TCPConn` or `*net.TCPConn`?

Comment: net.TCPConn.  But, (now that I've learned about it,) reflect.TypeOf() returns *net.TCPConn, and that does fix it.  I guess I was confused by the documentation not labeling net.Conn as an interface (unless you expand it).  Plus treating Go as Pythonic C++ maybe is not helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`TCPListener.AcceptTCP()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPListener.AcceptTCP), [`Accept`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPListener.Accept) just calls `AcceptTCP` and returns `*TCPConn` as an interface.

From http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/tcpsock_posix.go?s=7727:7771#L233

```
func (l *TCPListener) Accept() (Conn, error) {
    c, err := l.AcceptTCP() //notice this part
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return c, nil
}
```

Or like James mentioned in the comments, you could simply cast it to `tcpcon := conn.(*net.TCPConn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [How to Set Go net/http Socket Options - setsockopt() example](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/go-net-http-setsockopt-example/)

We could set `SO_LINGER` through `Control` of `net.Dialer`

```golang
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
        Control: func(network, address string, conn syscall.RawConn) error {
            var operr error
            if err := conn.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
                operr = syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), unix.SOL_SOCKET, unix.SO_LINGER, 1)
            }); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return operr
        },
    }

    client := http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{DialContext: dialer.DialContext}}
```

---

Another solution could be done through `DialContext` of `http.Transport`

```golang
type connDialer struct {
    c net.Conn
}

func (cd connDialer) DialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    tcpConn, ok := cd.c.(*net.TCPConn)
    if ok {
        tcpConn.SetLinger(0)
        return tcpConn, nil
    }
    return cd.c, nil
}

dialer := net.Dialer{}
conn, _ := dialer.DialContext(ctx, network, addr)

client := http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{DialContext: connDialer{c: conn}.DialContext}}
```